# How to statistically analyze the relationship of right skewed data

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, dataset

I struggle to analyze these continuous data:

[image]

[image]
The last four plots show the diagnostic plots on my model (model <- lm(data 1 ~ data 2).

My aim is to investigate the relationship between data 1 and data 2. Therefore I wanted to conduct a linear regression model. However, regarding that, the distribution is skewed and residuals are not normal (as shown in the normal qqplot) I am not sure how to continue. I already tried sqrt and log transformation, but the Normal-Q-Q-plot of the residuals always have tails.

Context:
data 1 shows an indicator of human pressure within nature conservation areas and data 2 shows an indicator of human pressure outside nature conservation areas (within a 2000 m buffer).
Zero values represent no human pressure and the higher the values the more intense the human pressure.

Comment: Describe your dependent variable. What type is it, some context. Better yet describe your data.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: What kind of thing is "human pressure"? Is it a percent, eg? What is the Y variable here, & what kind of data is it?

Comment: It is continuous data (data on effective mesh density to be exact) and Y = data 2, X = data 1

Comment: Maybe use robust regression?

Comment: Overlaps mightily with your previous question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392282/regression-analysis-with-right-skewed-data You can rewrite a question or delete a previous question, but don't just leave the previous version hanging there.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to analyze the relationship between two variables. This is not very helpful. There is an infinite number of ways two variables could "have a relationship" outside of the linear trend line.

If the OLS model is the *one model* you need to fit because it answers a direct scientific question, then you need to state that question differently: OLS specifically measures the mean difference in response comparing groups differing by one unit in the response. That is a very specific type of relationship between two variables. Given the very large sample size, we don't care that the residuals are skewed. The 95% CIs and p-values for the slope and intercept of the trendline should be correct. Prediction intervals can be calculated with more sophisticated methods if needed.

On the other hand, if you are exploring these data and generating hypotheses rather than confirming them, you can focus on the OLS trendline as but one possible summary of these data, and present those results alongside an OLS for the logged response and any other possible summary of interest.